# Taking out of the variable and using this to assign to this attribute

Tags: javascript

Created a function and would like to convert it into stand alone module or as you say OOP.

1. Moved the carlist and created as a global var.
2. I would like to console.log the dataname and define at a variable above. If I move the dataname outside than this.attr is giving me an error.
3. I would like to shorten this func, any best practices ideas?

**JavaScript /Jquery code**

```
(function(){
var el = $('#cartlist');
dataname = $(this).attr("data-name");
    el.on('click', '.add-one', function(event){
        shoppingCart.addIteamToCart(dataname, "description", 0, "image_url", 1);
        displaylistCartItems();
    });

    el.on("click", ".delete-button", function(event){

       shoppingCart.removeIteamFromCartAll(dataname);
       displaylistCartItems();
    });
    el.on("click", ".delete-one", function(event){
        shoppingCart.removeIteamFromCart(dataname);
        displaylistCartItems();
    });
    $("#cartlist").on("change", ".item-count",  function(event){
        var count = Number($(this).val());
        shoppingCart.setCountForItem(dataname, count);
    });
})();

// JQuery 
$(".add-to-cart").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var title = $(this).attr("data-title");
    var description = $(this).attr("data-description");
    var price = Number($(this).attr("data-price"));
    var image_url = $(this).attr("data-image_url");
    shoppingCart.addIteamToCart(title, description, price, image_url, 1);
    displaylistCartItems();
});
$("#clear-cart").click(function(event){
    shoppingCart.clearCart();
    displaylistCartItems();
});




function displaylistCartItems() {
    var cartArray = shoppingCart.listCartItems();
    var output = "";
    for (var i in cartArray) {
        output += "<li>"
        +cartArray[i].title
        +" <input class='item-count' style='height: 39px' type='number' data-name='"
        +cartArray[i].title
        +"' value='"+cartArray[i].count+"' >"
        +" x "+cartArray[i].price
        +" = "+cartArray[i].total
        +" <button class='add-one' data-name='"+cartArray[i].title+"'>+</butto>"
        +" <button class='delete-one' data-name='"+cartArray[i].title+"'>-</butto>"
        +" <button class='delete-button' data-name='"
        +cartArray[i].title+"'>X</button>"
        +"</li>"
    }
    $("#cartlist").html(output);
    $("#total-cart").html( shoppingCart.totalCart() );
    console.log(shoppingCart.countCart());
    $("#total-cart-count").html( shoppingCart.countCart() );    
    };
displaylistCartItems();
```

Link to plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/IGpJiosj0siFBXcbLxsq?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are passing a variable in the first function and then overriding it with a different one, and that is what causing your confusion.

Try this:

```
(function(){
var el = $('#cartlist');
var dataname = $(this).attr("data-name");
el.on('click', '.add-one', function(event){
    shoppingCart.addIteamToCart(dataname, "description", 0, "image_url", 1);
    displaylistCartItems();
});

el.on("click", ".delete-button", function(event){
   shoppingCart.removeIteamFromCartAll(dataname);
   displaylistCartItems();
});
el.on("click", ".delete-one", function(event){
    shoppingCart.removeIteamFromCart(dataname);
    displaylistCartItems();
});
})();
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but each time you trigger a 'click' on those classes, you will override the same variable.

Comment: I would like to make the code shoter. Currently I have   dataname = $(this).attr("data-name"); repeat 3 times. I could remove that line if I pass it as variable inside the function.

Comment: You can just initialize it outside the click events, I've updated my answer

Comment: thats what I did but when I click on the add button, delete button, it removed/add to other list item. The correct list item does not get selected. I have updated the code